# What is a API for a site

Tags: api

I have just started to lern about API's and was wondering how does an API work like the SE API on stackapps.com and was wondering if I have a progrsm like VS 2010 Pro how do I make a program with a API.

Comment: See also: [What is API Usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578089/what-is-api-usage), [What is the difference between an API , framework and middleware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934866/what-is-the-difference-between-an-api-framework-and-middleware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API stands for Application Programming Interface, so it is an interface that you provide in your system to be inter-operated from another system.

Normally the better these **approaches** are met, the better your API is:

1. Generic: can be used regard-less of the client programming platform, there are some constraints on this though.
2. Encapsulates your program's inner-logic and hide it: To let the modifications on system internals from a unique source.
3. Defines a known interface (contract) with a detailed precise specification.
4. Meets service-oriented best practices for the sake of security and extensibility.

See the related section in the right to dig more on the subject.

**EDIT:** Let's take Facebook API as an example, even though it is a powerful API, in the end, it consists of URLs which returns (useful) feedback, and there you see that is forming a script-like commands to work especially with their application from outside the system. So you can use that API in your program by calling the methods (in form of URLs).

Comment: nice answer but how do I use it in a program

Comment: @Benny - You've got to be kidding! You're going to need to do some actual learning... shock horror... on the fundamentals of programming. The question you are asking is so horrifically obtuse it borders on rude.

Answer (score 1):

As this is such a basic question which reveals a limited level of knowledge on programming, let alone the specifics of working with an API, I think my first suggestion would be the Wikipedia page on the subject:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface